# All 50 latest questions have score 0 or -1. Why do questions have such low scores on this Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

All 50 latest questions have score 0 or -1 ([mirror on web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210520021420/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&pagesize=50)):

- Questions with score of 0: 36
- Questions with score of -1: 14

Why do questions have such low scores on this Stack Exchange website?

It's the only Stack Exchange website where I saw this happened.

Comment: Related (keyword `neglected`): [1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1105/88163) (2012), [2](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3712/88163) (2014), (tag: [meta-tag:voting]): [3](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/710/88163) (2010), [4](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2701/88163) (2014)

Comment: Related: [5](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2491/88163)

Comment: I can't figure out which site is worse in terms of voting: Web Applications or Medical Sciences (cc @Rubén).

Comment: @user1271772 I think WebApps is even slightly worse. All 50 latest questions having score 0 or -1 is  rarely seen elsewhere. I do get a fair amount of unjustified downvotes on both sites though. Definitely the worse two websites anyway. If only all websites could be like space SE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've noticed this too, Franck.

My guess is because many people on StackExchange still don't value being nice and kind, and prefer to use their power to be negative, overly picky, and hyper-critical.

On some other StackExchange sites (especially Super User), it's common to simply get your good questions closed without any constructive feedback.

Some people just seem to not be interesting in providing others with free carrots.  Instead, they take those carrots, and try to use them as sticks.

I've been tempted to set up a question and answer site dedicated to people who choose to only be nice, kind, and helpful.  I would be okay if there were only 100 of us using that site, if that happens to be the total sum of people who can see the value of positive reinforcement and kindness.

Comment: Please invite me to that Q/A site when (or ***if***) it happens! You can email me at nike@hpqc.org.