# Kind reminder, voting is Important!

Tags: discussion, voting

## Voting is important

**Web Applications SE** as well all the other Stack Exchange sites are run by the community. After posting questions and answers one of the most importants actions that users can do to help the community is to vote (see [Why is voting important?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)). There are several types of votes, the basic are vote up (upvotes) and vote down (downvotes)

- [vote up](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

  > Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!
- [vote down](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

  > Downvotes should be used to indicate issues with quality, effort, or accuracy of a post

Vote up/down from *anonymous users and users with low reputation*, while are not included in the posts scores and doesn't impact on users reputation, they are logged as *anonymous feedback* which could be seen by users with the privilege [access to moderator tools](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and help to better moderate this site.

## Take your time for voting

- Avoid serial voting. Please read carefuly each post before voting.
- Avoid user targeted voting. Avoid focusing on voting only the posts of a single user. It's OK if looking at the main page, the questions page or the results page when searching for a tag or certain topics and you found many posts from the same user. When voting an answer, first read carefully the question and vote the answer considering the context provided by the question (is the answer actually answering the question?).

## Rewards for vote up/down

On Web Applications, to those users who have earned the privilege to up vote and down vote, there are *badges* awarded to recognize users that have reached certain milestones:

- [Supporter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/6/supporter) First up vote
- [Critic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic) First down vote
- [Suffrage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/193/suffrage) Use 30 votes in a day
- [Vox Populi](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/202/vox-populi) Use the maximum 40 votes in a day
- [Sportmanship](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/sportsmanship) Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score
- [Electorate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/electorate) Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

## The outcome

Voting helps to mantain the community healthy.

- Helps to make good posts easier to find, i.e. when sorting by score.
- Helps to clean the site as posts with zero or negative scores, not enough comments and no answers will be "deleted" making easier to find helpful content. "Deleted" posts might be found by post authors, >10K rep, diamond moderators, staff and in https://data.stackexchange.com.
- Motivates community members to improve their posts and continue participating. Make them possible to earn privileges to increase their participation possibilities.

At the end, we will have a *public repository of high quality content* in the form of questions and answers.

## Neglected posts

If you have ideas to find neglected posts regarding voting, post each of them as a new answer to make it easier to ask clarification, provide feedback, and when needed coordinate follow-up actions.

## Unrelated stuff

If you have concerns about something different about voting up / down, i.e. unanswered posts, new tags, etc., please look if there is already a related post or add a new one.

---

#### Users with >10k rep.

There are 15 users >10k rep. For those that are part of thee group:

**Access to the Anonymous and Low Reputation Post Feedback**

1. Click on **Review Queues** > **Tools**.
2. Scroll to the **Links** section and click on [anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) (only available for users with reputation >= 10K.

---

## FAQ

### From Meta Stack Exchange

- **[When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/289691)**
- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/289691)
- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/289691)

### Historical posts from this site

- [What does voting mean and why is it important?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/710/88163) from October 10th, 2010

Comment: From https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters voters by period : week = 0 users; month = 3 users, quarter / year = 8 users

Comment: The week stats were 0, because were taken  just after they were reset. There morning there was 2 users. Current stats week = 0 users; month 3 users, quarter / year = 9 users. (need to check the quarter / year number of the last week).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for voting on unanswered questions having at least one answer

[is:question isanswered:0 answers:1 closed:0 hasaccepted:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3A0+answers%3A1+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0)

As of February 26, 2023 returns 3,245 questions.

To be considered answered the question should have at least one answer with a score >= 2. Unanswered question are ramdomly selected to be bumped by Community user, one each hour.

Due to the activity of Web Applications SE, it's common to find the homepage full of Community user bumped questions. IMO this is bad for the site as most of the bumped questions are questions are still open due to the lack of voting.

Related

- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/289691)
- [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/289691)
- [Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/289691)

Answer (score 1):

Top 100 questions by the number of times that were bumped by Community User

The list was generated by using a SEDE query. Apparently, these questions are +5 years old.

| Rank | Question | Tags | Count | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [How does Mint.com Budget Once work?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33314) | [mint.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mint.com) | 46 | One answer |
| 1 | [Download list of contact information and check if Google Account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44237) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-workspace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace)[google-contacts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts)[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) | 46 | One answer |
| 1 | [Maintaining user submitted entries state so it can be viewed when page reloads in Cognito Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86660) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 46 | One answer |
| 1 | [Select drop down field in one Cognito Form where the values come from another form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87335) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 46 | One answer |
| 1 | [Edit multiple entries in Cognito Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90718) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 46 | One answer |
| 6 | [Selecting a single column from all rows for chart range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90384) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-sheets-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-charts) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [Field edits that are exported automatically in Cognito Forms PDF attachment?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86945) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [Conditional File Attachment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86620) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[attachment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attachment) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [How to validate Cognito Form using existing data on another application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87111) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [How do I send confirmation emails to multiple respondent addresses when entries are submitted in Cognito Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74912) | [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)[cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [Provide another user permissions access to see submitted Cognito forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76017) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[permissions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [Calculations and repeating sections](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82272) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [Changing the name of a Facebook app developer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36589) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-apps)[facebook-developers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-developers) | 45 | Closed |
| 6 | [Is it possible to quickly invite people to join a group rather than just adding them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54013) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) | 45 | Answers +2 |
| 6 | [Notification of posts including your business place on Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66308) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)[facebook-notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-notifications) | 45 | Answers +2 |
| 6 | [Calculate Total Based on Selected Options Part 2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92359) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 6 | [How can I assign a price or collect payment for each repeating section?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92560) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | Answers +2 |
| 6 | [Can you change the status of multiple entries in a Cognito form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92919) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 45 | One answer |
| 19 | [Querying multiple ranges from form responses to new sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94722) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-sheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-query) | 44 | One answer |
| 19 | [Organize / categorize forms into named folders?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94860) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 44 | One answer |
| 19 | [How do I send a piece of HTML in Outlook Web Access?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39059) | [html](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html)[outlook-web-access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access) | 44 | Closed |
| 19 | [Cognito to Sharepoint Integrations seems to be using the Display Name from Cognito](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91725) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[sharepoint](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint) | 44 | One answer |
| 19 | [Need a formula to synchronise "Entry" with existing numbering](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92101) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 44 | One answer |
| 19 | [Decimal.Parse returning NULL value on text calculation displaying IF result](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92273) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 44 | One answer |
| 25 | [Assign a value to a drop down selection](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91336) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 43 | Answers +2 |
| 26 | [Is it possible to link one calendar to another inside the same form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95612) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 42 | One answer |
| 26 | [Why did friend's likes disappear from my posts on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/97217) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) | 42 | Answers +2 |
| 28 | [Adding user data to form entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98097) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 41 | One answer |
| 28 | [Checking which time is more recent](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98211) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 41 | One answer |
| 30 | [Photos received through Hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98999) | [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) | 40 | One answer |
| 30 | [Can I change text on "Save" button for Save & Resume Feature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99171) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 40 | One answer |
| 30 | [Email aliases on Windows Live Domains for custom domains](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42900) | [office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365) | 40 | Answers +2 |
| 30 | [Blogger profile changes to nameless profile when I try to follow blogs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/55437) | [blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogger) | 40 | Zero answers |
| 34 | [Connect a mail.live.com address to an office365.com account - unusual activity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99634) | [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com)[office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365) | 39 | One answer |
| 34 | [How to include URLs of attachments in exported spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99971) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 39 | One answer |
| 34 | [Validate text field to hold only digits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100080) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 39 | One answer |
| 37 | [Accessing encrypted form submissions via email notification](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100199) | [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)[cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[encryption](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption)[ssl](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl) | 38 | One answer |
| 37 | ["If then" calculations based on value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100872) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 38 | One answer |
| 37 | [Form entries not appearing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100911) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 38 | One answer |
| 37 | [How can we get the referring URL value in a Cognito form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101106) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 38 | One answer |
| 37 | [How to remove notification for suggested friend on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101662) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-friends) | 38 | Answers +2 |
| 37 | [Can I limit a text field in Cognito Forms to NOT allow alpha characters?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99982) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[data-validation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-validation) | 38 | One answer |
| 43 | [How to add persistent submit button to multi page forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101732) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 37 | One answer |
| 43 | [Prefilling a Cognito form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101035) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 37 | One answer |
| 43 | [Does adding a Google+ Instant Upload photo to an album create multiple copies?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37895) | [google-plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus)[google-plus-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-photos) | 37 | Closed |
| 46 | [Prevent 'reply all' in Facebook group message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85801) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) | 36 | Answers +2 |
| 46 | [If I like a friend's old post, would my 'Like' appear to our friend's (mutual) news feed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101920) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy)[facebook-privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-privacy)[facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) | 36 | Answers +2 |
| 46 | [Disable Google groups mail delivery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102977) | [google-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-groups) | 36 | One answer |
| 49 | [Calculation Field referencing field in an separate form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102525) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 35 | One answer |
| 49 | [Line break in question label](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103781) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 35 | One answer |
| 49 | [How do I stop event invites from a particular group without leaving it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103946) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups)[facebook-events](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-events) | 35 | One answer |
| 49 | [Adding email attachment to Google Photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95705) | [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)[google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)[google-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-photos)[gmail-attachments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-attachments) | 35 | One answer |
| 49 | [Force embedded YouTube videos to play at specific quality resolution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62888) | [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube)[embed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embed)[iframe](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iframe) | 35 | Answers +2 |
| 54 | [Scheduled exports (emailed?)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98443) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 34 | One answer |
| 54 | [Is there some way wherein an end user would see all the entries submitted to a particular form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103649) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 34 | One answer |
| 54 | [How do I make my PayPal account have the features of a credit card processor and not just a PayPal button?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103986) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[paypal](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paypal) | 34 | One answer |
| 54 | [Keep posts on Friends' timelines from appearing on mine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103307) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) | 34 | Answers +2 |
| 54 | [How do you upload an image in Sourceforge.wiki?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104555) | [upload](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upload)[sourceforge](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sourceforge) | 34 | One answer |
| 54 | [Can I indicate from which customer a Trello task is for?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104687) | [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello) | 34 | Answers +2 |
| 54 | [Can I invite people to like page who liked the post when I shared into a Facebook group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104783) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) | 34 | One answer |
| 54 | [Making a condition on a question to only be asked to a certain amount of people](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105027) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 34 | One answer |
| 62 | [How to use Facebook pages shortcuts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106074) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)[url-shortening](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-shortening) | 33 | One answer |
| 62 | [Lookup a value?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104021) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[vlookup](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vlookup) | 33 | One answer |
| 62 | [Change Facebook "Watching" activity to "Watched"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104246) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline)[status](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status) | 33 | One answer |
| 62 | [Dynamically displaying content entered into a repeating section on a subsequent page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87199) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 33 | One answer |
| 62 | [Coloring cells according to the value to which its content is closest](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89053) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting) | 33 | Closed |
| 67 | [Trying to do a calculation with a Choice field and Decimal in Cognito Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106275) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 32 | One answer |
| 67 | [Summing values from multiple sheets with names specified in cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106639) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) | 32 | Answers +2 |
| 67 | [Is there option to download all the attached documents of the Cognito form entries?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106752) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 32 | One answer |
| 70 | [Counting rows where condition is met in at least one column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107177) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) | 31 | One answer |
| 70 | [Does Cognito Forms allow the changing of who is sending the email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107209) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 31 | One answer |
| 70 | [Copy range from specific values to top of another sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107470) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) | 31 | Answers +2 |
| 70 | [Does Facebook automatically archive older posts in a group? How can I access these archived posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91793) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) | 31 | Answers +2 |
| 70 | [Facebook getting search history from Gmail, LinkedIn and Twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95750) | [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)[facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)[privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy)[linkedin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) | 31 | Answers +2 |
| 75 | [Does adding new friends to an old post show as new on the new friends' timelines?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66727) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) | 30 | One answer |
| 75 | [Clear emails automatically from sent folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108082) | [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) | 30 | One answer |
| 75 | [Extract Google Calendar data to Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107174) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-workspace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace)[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)[google-calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar) | 30 | One answer |
| 75 | [Is there any way to disable a calculation field?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108668) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 30 | One answer |
| 75 | [Is there a way to number uploaded files (specifically photos) in Cognito Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108706) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 30 | One answer |
| 80 | [How can I copy big data from Shared folder on Google Drive without downloading them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108383) | [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)[google-drive-sharing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sharing)[google-drive-shared-folder](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-shared-folder) | 29 | Answers +2 |
| 80 | [Pulling up and re-using historic data after a payment is made](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108748) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 29 | One answer |
| 80 | [Hide products that aren't selected in the Cognito confirmation email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109229) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 29 | One answer |
| 80 | [How would I add line breaks for visual formatting of a Cognito form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109396) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 29 | One answer |
| 80 | [Filter email based on Gmail plus operator, with wildcard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101510) | [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)[google-workspace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace)[gmail-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-search) | 29 | One answer |
| 80 | [Import Cognito Forms data from another page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100285) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 29 | One answer |
| 86 | [How to see all flagged emails in Outlook.com?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/102124) | [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) | 28 | Answers +2 |
| 86 | [Facebook shortcut Alt + Del for archiving messages has stopped working](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/62483) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[keyboard-shortcuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Show all posts and comments in a Facebook group that I am a member of, not an admin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36853) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Choice list autocomplete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109378) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Is there a way to eliminate options when quantity hits 0?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109659) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Merging PDF upload](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109763) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | Closed |
| 86 | [Use calculation to provide the next Friday based on submission date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110207) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[calculator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Creative Cognito Forms notification email that contains all form details](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110216) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)[notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications)[formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Select case conditional logic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110619) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Fields on form blank after viewing web link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110680) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | One answer |
| 86 | [Filtering entries by a date range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109253) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | Answers +2 |
| 86 | [Limit sub-user access to specific filters on same form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108876) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 28 | One answer |
| 98 | [New document version and old document version](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110656) | [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms) | 27 | One answer |
| 98 | [Show/Hide Rows based on text in a cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110266) | [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)[google-apps-script-triggers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-triggers) | 27 | One answer |
| 98 | [YouTube higher quality = no buffering](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40520) | [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) | 27 | One answer |

P.S. +50% (57) questions are tagged [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms)

##### Related

- [What is the point to show to anonymous users posts bumped by Community user? How to prevent that bad questions be bumped in low participation sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388634/289691)

Answer (score 0):

While the homepage might the natural place to start looking about which questions to vote, here is a suggestion about were to start oriented to give some attention to neglected questions:

[answers:0 views:...10 created:2022 closed:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Active&pagesize=50&q=answers%3A0%20views%3A...10%20created%3A2022%20closed%3A0&searchOn=3)

returns 581 open questions created in 2022, having zero answers, up to 10 views, most recent active first.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for voting on neglected answers

[is:answer isaccepted:0 lastactive:2022 votes:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20isaccepted%3A0%20lastactive%3A2022%20votes%3A0)

returns 1,131 answers that have 0 votes, are not accepted and were last active in 2022.

[is:answer isaccepted:0 lastactive:2022 votes:0 [google-sheets]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0+lastactive%3A2022+votes%3A0+%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D) returns 610 answers (almost 50%)

[is:answer isaccepted:0 lastactive:2022 votes:0 [gmail]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0+lastactive%3A2022+votes%3A0+%5Bgmail%5D) returns 92 answers

[is:answer isaccepted:0 lastactive:2022 votes:0 [youtube]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20isaccepted%3A0%20lastactive%3A2022%20votes%3A0%20%5Bfacebook*%5D) returns 49

[is:answer isaccepted:0 lastactive:2022 votes:0 [facebook*]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20isaccepted%3A0%20lastactive%3A2022%20votes%3A0%20%5Bfacebook*%5D) returns 29

Answer (score 0):

Idea from [Search for question with positive score where all answers have zero score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261610/289691)

Forked and adapted from the query shared in [rene's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297930/289691):

[Search for open questions with positive score where All answers (2 or more) have zero score](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1724194/search-for-open-questions-with-positive-score-where-all-answers-2-or-more-have)

Note: Data in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated once a week, on Sundays. The Help mentions the date of the last update.